# python split list of strings, where index out of range

Tags: python-2.7, split

How do I return the second alpha character [if there is a second alpha character] of each item in a list? If there is not a second alpha character do nothing.

list = ["a b", "c d", "e"]

```
for item in list:
    x = item.split()[1]
```

The last loop returns "IndexError: list index out of range" due to the fact that there is not a second item.

Comment: *My example is simple enough to understand what I'm asking for.* - It's simple enough to understand that there is no second item, but you haven't said what you *want* to happen next - get the "e" anyway? Get an empty string? Get no output for that item? Throw an error and fail the whole loop, but handle it without the program crashing?

Comment: So, when there is just one *item*, do you wish to discard it or print that item as it is?

Comment: Actually if you read the question I said exactly what I wanted "I want to return the second item in each string"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because there's the item `"e"` which is split into one chunk (indexed with `0`)
Also, don't give variable *reserved* name as `list`.
For your simple case you may use the following:

```
l = ["a b", "c d", "e"]
result = [i.split()[1] if ' ' in i else i for i in l]
print(result)
```

The output:

```
['b', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: "i.split()[1] if ' ' in i" makes sense. Could you explain "else i for i in 1"?

Comment: @Rthomas529, `i.split()[1] if ' ' in i else i` - means: "include the last item from sequence if that sequence has space as delimiter - otherwise include the item as is"

Answer (score 0):

This takes the item even if the length of it is 1(that is, it cannot be split)

```
x = [] #creates a list to hold the values
for item in list:
        if(len(item)) == 1:
            x.append(item)
        else:
            x.append(item.split()[1])
print(x)
```

This, ignores the item if it is not splittable:

```
x = [] #creates a list to hold the values.
for item in list:
    if len(item) > 1:
        x.append(item.split()[1])
print(x)
```